# Must bounded, closed, smooth curves with long straights have sharp bends?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Consider the family of bounded, closed, and continous curves $\Gamma$, i.e. for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$, we have $\gamma : [0, 1) \to [0, 1]^2$. Within this family, I am interested in curves that maximize the length of the straight segments (i.e. segments where the jacobian is large).

Intuitively, such curves should have long straights interleaved with "sharp bends", i.e. the maximum curvature of along the curve should be large. Is this intuition correct? Is there a known result formalizing this intuition (given that it's correct)?